# php foreach loop in_array doesn't display positive result

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [subject] => Computer [price] => 33.00 [quantity] => 1 ) ) )
```

I have an array like this above, but when i use in_array like below to check the subject value, it will display negative result.

```
foreach ($cart_info as $item){
    foreach ($item as $item2){
        if (in_array("Computer", $item2['subject'])) {
        echo "Yes";
        }else{
            echo "No";
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing a string as your second parameter under `in_array()` which is wrong.

Comment: Do not use two for loops the first for loop would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

**haystack Should be an array**

Please check the documentation for `in_array`

`bool in_array ( mixed $needle , array $haystack [, bool $strict = FALSE ] )`

```
 haystack

    The array.
strict

    If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the in_array() function will also check the types of the needle in the haystack.
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/in_array

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a wrong key so you are not getting desired output.

it should be

```
in_array("Computer", $cart_info[0])
```

or

```
in_array("Computer", $cart_info)
```

or even

```
 if($item2 == "Computer")
```

instead of

```
in_array("Computer", $item2['subject'])
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if (in_array("Computer", $item2)) {
   echo "Yes";
}else{
   echo "No";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `$item2['subject']` is not an array. In your case use:

```
foreach ($cart_info as $item){
    foreach ($item as $item2){
        if ("Computer" == $item2['subject'])) {
        echo "Yes";
        }else{
            echo "No";
        }   
    }
}
```